# Why is execution time of two functions dependent on code order?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time

I wrote two similar functions that cast two numpy uint16 into one uint32. I wanted to test their execution time to see which one is faster. The result is different depending on which function is being run first.

```py
def int32(x):
    return 65536 * x[:, 0] + x[:, 1]

def int32shift(x):
    return np.bitwise_or(np.left_shift(x[:, 0], 8), x[:, 1])

def parsePayloadshift(payload):
    np_payload = np.fromstring(payload, dtype='>u2').reshape((-1, 38))
    flags, t0, t1, data = int32shift(np_payload[:, :2]), int32shift(np_payload[:, 2:4]), int32shift(np_payload[:, 4:6]), np_payload[:, 6:]


def parsePayload(payload):
    np_payload = np.fromstring(payload, dtype='>u2').reshape((-1, 38))
    flags, t0, t1, data = int32(np_payload[:, :2]), int32(np_payload[:,2:4]), int32(np_payload[:, 4:6]), np_payload[:,6:]

#using multiplication

start_time = time.time()
parsePayload(payload)
end_time = time.time()
time_slice = end_time - start_time
print(time_slice)

# using shift

start_time = time.time()
parsePayloadshift(payload)
end_time = time.time()
time_slice2 = end_time - start_time
print(time_slice2)
```

I observed that the function that is being run first is the slower one. So I've run a code testing this sequence:

shift, multiplication, shift

Here are the results:
0.0002779960632324219  #shift
0.00019311904907226562 #multiplication
0.00013971328735351562 #shift again

Why is this test behaving that way?
How should I properly test these functions to see which one is faster?

Comment: they do not differ in an order of magnitude, why do you think the second execution is faster? also it doesn't seem to be related to Python3.6, but probably to `numpy` which is written in C under-the-hood and needs additional time on first function invocation to load internals

Comment: `time.time()` isn't a particularly accurate method of measuring code execution.

Comment: @AzatIbrakov thank you for your answer. The times tend to vary from e-04 to e-05. From your comment I assume this difference is neglible. I'll just stick with either one of those functions in this case.

Comment: @user3483203 is timeit the better method? I used time since it allowed me to pass arguments to the function

Comment: `timeit` lets you pass arguments to the functions as well

Comment: It is possible that numpy does some global optimization on the first run. So consecutive runs are faster.

Comment: There may be CPU-, disk- or otherwise caching being done. Using `timeit` avoids that, as it will first do a warm-up run. After that, it runs the function several times, and takes the average of the (3) fastest runs. So timeit is a much better way of measuring the speed of a individual function than just measuring the start and stop time of a single run and comparing those.